Migrations worked initially but now produce strange errors
Long story short, I made a successful initial migration with EF Core 8. However, shortly I found some rather minor things here and there and tried to amend them, but attempts to make a new migration henceforth ended up erroring out with quite strange errors. This is puzzling because the initial migration went smoothly but now it just refuses to work.
I made a separate project and tried to add the model classes one by one till it stops working.
This is a setup where the project still works:
internal class Dictionary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DictionaryEntry> Entries { get; set; }
}

internal class DictionaryEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public Dictionary Dictionary { get; set; }
}

internal abstract class DictionaryEntry<TValue>: DictionaryEntry
{
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}

internal abstract class GroupedEntry<TValue, TEntryGroup>: DictionaryEntry<TValue>
    where TEntryGroup : DictionaryEntry
{
    public virtual TEntryGroup EntryGroup { get; set; }
}

internal class EntryGroup<TEntry>: DictionaryEntry
    where TEntry : DictionaryEntry
{
    public virtual ICollection<TEntry> Entries { get; set; } 
    public virtual EntryGroup<TEntry> Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntryGroup<TEntry>> Children { get; set; }
}

internal class EntryGroup<TGroupEntry, TEntry>: EntryGroup<TEntry>
    where TGroupEntry : DictionaryEntry
    where TEntry : DictionaryEntry
{
    public virtual TGroupEntry GroupEntry { get; set; } = null!;
}

internal class EntryClassA: DictionaryEntry<uint>
{
    public virtual EntryClassB LinkedDocumentation { get; set; }
}

internal class EntryClassB: GroupedEntry<uint, EntryGroup_EntryClassAB>;

internal class EntryGroup_EntryClassAB: EntryGroup<EntryClassB, EntryClassA>

Adding these classes causes errors:
internal abstract class Entry_ClassCBase: GroupedEntry<uint, EntryGroup_ClassC>;
internal class Entry_ClassCGroup: Entry_ClassCBase;
internal class Entry_ClassC: Entry_ClassCBase;
internal class EntryGroup_ClassC: EntryGroup<Entry_ClassCGroup, Entry_ClassC>;

In this particular case it is due to

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'EntryGroup_ClassC.GroupEntry' and 'Entry_ClassCGroup.EntryGroup'. To identify the dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship, configure them independently via separate method chains in 'OnModelCreating'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

But in the main application the model had already included those same classes when the first migration was successfully created so I do not understand the sudden origin of the errors. I can painstakingly fix errors one by one, but I do not want to, of course. My only theory is that when I fixed those issues I probably shuffled some code that made the model work, but I do not understand which.
Here is my context:
namespace Program
{
    sealed class CultureInfoConverter: ValueConverter<CultureInfo, string>
    {
        public CultureInfoConverter() : base(static (v) => v.Name, static (v) => CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(v)) { }
    }

    internal partial class Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options): DbContext(options)
    {
        public DbSet<Dictionary> Dictionaries { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            _ = modelBuilder.
                HasCollation("en_natural", locale: "en-u-kn-true", provider: "icu", deterministic: false);
            _ = modelBuilder.UseHiLo(null);

            _ = modelBuilder.Owned<Oid>();
            _ = modelBuilder.Owned<Version>();

            _ = modelBuilder.Entity<Dictionary>().
                HasDiscriminator();
            _ = modelBuilder.Entity<Dictionary>().Property<uint>("RowVersion").
                IsRowVersion();
            _ = modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryEntry>().
                HasDiscriminator();
            _ = modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryEntry>().Property<uint>("RowVersion").
                IsRowVersion();
            _ = modelBuilder.Entity<Dictionary>().Property<ulong>("Id");
            _ = modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryEntry>().Property<ulong>("Id");
        }
        protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
        {
            _ = configurationBuilder.Properties<string>().
                UseCollation("en_natural").
                AreUnicode();

            _ = configurationBuilder.Properties<CultureInfo>().
                HaveConversion<CultureInfoConverter>();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => _ = optionsBuilder.UseExceptionProcessor();
    }
}


Where are DirectoryEntry and Oid? And which database provider is this about? Also, side note, remove this _ =  addition, it serves no purpose.

The former was a typo. The latter is the standard System.Security.Cryptography.Oid type.

Oh, also, it is https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html, @GertArnold.

Try to define the foreign key explicitly for the one-to-one relationship causing the issue, you need to make sure that EF Core knows which side is the principal and which side is the dependent. You can do this using the HasForeignKey() method in the OnModelCreating. ......HasForeignKey<Entry_ClassCGroup>(e => e.EntryGroupId); Then also do it on the other classes causing issues.

So a couple of things to check (the only things I can think of):
EF Core can get confused with relationships in complex inheritance setups particularly around which side of a one-to-one relationship is dependent. This seems to be the case with EntryGroup_ClassC.GroupEntry and Entry_ClassCGroup.EntryGroup. Maybe try explicitly setting the foreign key in OnModelCreating to clarify the mapping.
Then continuing on the complex inheritance issue EF Core usually needs you to define foreign keys manually for one-to-one or one-to-many relationships. I'd say go through each relationship in your GroupedEntry and EntryGroup classes and explicitly set the HasForeignKey or use WithOne/WithMany to be sure each mapping is as clear as possible.

I know, but I do not understand why did this stop to work all of sudden. I still have the first migration to show for it.
